Ubuntu 22.04 can't make 2 xbox controllers work simultaneously
I have a Xbox 360 and a Xbox Series controllers, both working with USB. Both are working individually on Ubuntu 22.04 but when I try to play a local multiplayer game with both at the same time, only the first that is plugged is working.
The issue doesn't appear on windows 11 on the same computer.
I tried already to install xboxdrv but it just disconnected my mouse while not solving my problem...
Do you have any ideas ?
Thanks
Edit :
When I restarted my computer, the 2 controllers were working but my mouse was disconnected. So it seems that I can't have 3 devices like mouse or controllers plugged at the same time

Ok it seems that it was linked to the usb port I used for my controllers and mouse. When I plugged on into another port, it solved my issue.
It doesn't explain why it's working on windows and not ubuntu though...
